# display: table-cell centering with two elements, rather than three

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have a working example of vertically centering elements of unknown height, using three elements:

```
<section>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
    </div>
</section>​
```

And the CSS:

```
section {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

There's also a JSFiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6KS9/

However I'd like to avoid using unnecessary wrappers if possible. Eg, having the img itself display as table-cell:

```
div {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
​
```

However this doesn't work - see the JSFiddle example at http://jsfiddle.net/U2c9R/ -  the img is not centered within the div.

Is it possible to vertically center an image of unknown size within its parent using only two elements?

**Edit:** I'm aware of Flexbox, and intending to throw out the table cell hack completely once IE9 dies. But right now I need to support old browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the CSS3 [Flexible Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/).

You should check the browser availability. As you can see by the `-webkit` vendor prefix my Example currently works only in `-webkit`-based render engines. But i'm pretty sure it'll work in most modern browsers.

Here is an overview of browsers which supporting the Flexible Box Model: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

```
div {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

**Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/U2c9R/4/

### Update

For Cross-browser support for the CSS3 Flexible Box Model you could use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) and a proper [Polyfill](https://github.com/doctyper/flexie) which adds support for `IE 6-9` and `Opera 10.0+`. The only hint is, this wouldn't work without JavaScript. But maybe this is an option?

Comment: I've moderated you up - my mixins that actually apply the rules are mrked 'delete me once flexbox is everywhere' - but this is for an app that needs to support IE9.

Comment: The polyfill is actually pretty reasonable (and less code to clear up later). If nobody shows how to do the hack with only two elements then I think this is probably the best answer.